# How to mask a line renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a trail that follows my sprite around using the line renderer. I want that line renderer to interact with a sprite mask (be visible inside a sprite mask), but there isn't a mask interaction option on the line renderer itself. I am trying to do this in 2D

I have tried using a render texture with a second camera just for the trail without any luck.

How would i achieve this?

Comment: ...i'm just going to comment that "sadly, what you want is surprisingly complicated", so that you're not surprised if you don't get any proper answer for very long.

because proper answer would involve second camera and some depthmasking trickery, or outright having to write your own shader for the line, which you can depth-mask.

in short, i'm afraid there's no easy way.

Comment: rendertexture with a second camera should work, except that rendertexture needs to be assigned into some kind of image that can be masked by spritemask.

Comment: OK thank you, I'll keep exploring the render texture method. I need this to work for mobile, so It should be low cost on the performance. I have previously achieved the masked trail with instantiating circle game objects for a trail, but that doesn't fully work for me because if the sprite is moving too quick a few trail objects don't have time to spawn

Comment: "but that doesn't fully work for me because if the sprite is moving too quick a few trail objects don't have time to spawn" <- that's because you're just spawning one of them each frame on the sprite's current position. try each frame spawning several of them at some maximum distance from each other along the line from previous frame's position to the current frame's position ;) ...but mobiles won't like you spawning so many objects, so then look into pooling them.

Comment: OK, will try that. Thank you

Comment: The objects won't be in the scene for very long, they get destroyed after a few seconds and the maximum number of trail game objects doesn't exceed 50 at a time. The game objects are small sprites that don't have any scripts or colliders on them and they also ignore raycasts, so I don't think I will have problems with performance with this method

Comment: NO, that's EXACTLY why you will have performance problems, and will need to use pooling. Instantiating and then destroying objects all the time creates a lot of garbage for garbage collector to collect all the time, and garbage collection is slow. Therefore you'll want to use object pooling, meaning disabling/hiding the objects instead of destroying them, and then moving them to new position and re-enabling them, instead of instantiating new ones. Creating objects, destroying objects, and garbage collecting is slow. You want to avoid that, and pooling does that.

Comment: Will look into object pooling, thank you for the advice